# How to find the local Jenkins workspace directory in windows 10

Tags: jenkins

[image: Jenkins workspace folder image]

I tried to figure it out where my Jenkins jobs are stored in my local directory.

Started by user MOIZUDDIN
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Myfirstjob
[Myfirstjob] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8566925460296395223.bat

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Myfirstjob>echo "Assalamulaiakum"
"Assalamulaiakum"

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Myfirstjob>exit 0
Finished: SUCCESS

I haven't found the ProgramData file in windows 10.

Jenkins job files are not showing in windows 10

Comment: Look for Local(C:)

Answer (score 0):

We can find the Jenkins jobs file using the gitbash app in windows 10. Jenkins Workspace directory shows when you use the command:

```
#ls -a
```

to check hidden files.